# How to verify DPFP finger print from SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, digital-persona-sdk

I have saved the dpfp template in a `varbinary(max)` column, now I am retrieving it from database, converting to `byte[]`, then deserializing it, and then putting in the verify() method, but an error occurs:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8

How I am getting the data is shown here:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Windows\me;Initial Catalog=Enroll;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa ;  Password=sa123");

cn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select varb from employee where employeeid='127'", cn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
bytes= ConvertDataSetToByteArray(dt);

Template = new DPFP.Template();
Template.DeSerialize(bytes);

<b>Verificator.Verify(features, Template, ref result);</b>
UpdateStatus(result.FARAchieved);

if (result.Verified)
    MakeReport("The fingerprint was VERIFIED.");
else
    MakeReport("The fingerprint was NOT VERIFIED.");
```

This `Verify()` is not verifying the data coming from DB.

Where is my mistake? In the conversion? Or in not getting data properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConvertDataSetToByteArray() method should be excluded 
`System.Byte` in datable will be convert in to `byte[]` by:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    bytes = (byte[])row["varb"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was storage in the sql server database.

I was using varbinary (MAX) and the fingerprint requires binary (1632). I modified this in the database and it worked.